# Normal image manipulation for bas relief

Tags: modeling

I'm Mr.Wong,I just enquiry can we use a face image create relief make a commemorative coin by using blender?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: Yes you can use Blender to model a coin where a normal map or bump map is used to create the portrait on it.

Comment: There are different ways of achieving this, Normal and Bump maps are one, Displacement Maps another, both are for rendering. If you need to physically create the geometry, the Displacement Modifier might be for you, see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html?highlight=displacement%20modifier on how to use an image in the Displacement Modifier. Please clarify your question in terms of what you are after.

Comment: If you can capture or derive a depth-map of the subject, [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122473/35559) might help..