# What workflow would you use to model a pendant like this?

Tags: modeling, workflow

[image: Pendant]
Some cool pendants I came across online, what would be the best workflow to use to get this type of result?

Comment: it depends what's the final goal, do you need real 3D or can you use a normal map? You could convert this photo into a normal map, or sculpt and bake the normals. Or you can model it but it will take time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122460/how-do-i-convert-a-3d-model-into-a-bas-relief-using-mist