# Basrelief node setup for rendering height map

Tags: modeling, materials, shaders

H i  , i want to convert a 3d model to a basrelief using cycles node setup and render it in a height map i achieved this results but thats not what i wanted , i want to find a way thru node setup that reduces the over heighted areas without reducing the detail , also i want the edges of the model bend into floor plane procedurally thru baked map .
[image]

this is the model :
[image]
and this is the unfortune result
[image]

I want to somehow keep the curvature of my model and only reduce the differences , i saw an addon on youtube called basrelief , and i don't have access to their purchase services , but it does the exact thing , which i guess it happens thru nodes here is the link if that video :
https://youtu.be/q3hr54dtnbU

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122473/35559

Comment: @RobinBetts very thanks for answer , but thats not what i wanted , maybe see the video, to help me more ?

Comment: @RobinBetts also there is a software called shaperover you can see the advertisements of the software to see the differences, it'll do the thing , but its not for sale ...

Comment: Got it... what you're looking at is normal > height conversion.. not a trivial problem...

Comment: YES! is it possible to do that within blender ?

Comment: Unlikely: as far as I can see, the conversion is iterative..not ideally suited to nodes, but, you never know...

Comment: @RobinBetts I found this video a little bit useful https://youtu.be/vaDAiH-IeN4 But it wasn't too good , also i tried to use awesomenormal software , but it didn't get me the good result , i guess i need to buy shaperover which isn't for sell , I guess i should find a way to reduce the heights but keeping the curvature of model .

Comment: Hmmmm. I'm simply not prepared to watch 'information' videos which do not perform the most basic function of communication. Whoever made that one can jump in a lake.

Comment: @RobinBetts Hah XD , sorry about that , but this is what i want here : https://youtu.be/ZXPn2PF_Wy4 it shows that this guys is using belnder and photoshop to generate those reliefs can you guide me what did he done ?