# How would I make my profile picture engrained on a coin?

Tags: modeling, shaders, normals

Pick up a coin, you can feel the image on it, it's 3d. That's what I'm trying to achieve. I already put my profile picture into photoshop and made a black/white image of it, which I want to map the texture of the coin. I already tried to use the bump and displacement nodes in the shader editor, but those seem to only make the illusion of a 3d image, when I look from the side the coin is totally flat, and it looks terrible.

Comment: Have you tried the Displace modifier for example? You'll have real displacement. Also the Displacement node even though I think it's easier with the Displace modifier...

Comment: Hi :). If you're using Displacement node, you need to enable true displacement in the material ;)

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122473/35559